# Conditionally setting nginx directives inside location blocks

Tags: nginx

## What I want

I want to be able to set multiple nginx directives conditionally inside location blocks. For example, for a location /example, I want to set `proxy_cache_revalidate on` if `$http_method` is POST, otherwise I want to set `proxy_cache_revalidate off`. I also want more directives like `proxy_cache_valid` and `add_header` to be set conditionally based on different variables like the remote ip, cookies, content type and more.

For a different location, these conditions must be able to look completely differently.

## But why?

I don't know. I'm being paid to do this, there is a lot of money behind this and I don't have any say in these requirements. No sane person would want to implement this. Hopefully I will learn more about nginx along the way, though.

## What I tried

My first idea was to use `if` statements, but apparently [those are evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) and can not be used inside location blocks in the way I wanted. If it was doable, I would have written something like this:

```
http {
    [...]
    server {
        [...]
        location /example {
            [...]

            if ($http_method = "POST") {
                proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            }
            else {  # yeah okay, there is no else-statement anyway, but you get the point...
                proxy_cache_revalidate off;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I thought I might be able to work around that using maps. Those can't be used in location blocks either, so things would get messy, but potentially doable. I would have to create lots and lots of maps, a couple of them per location block.

But it turns out this doesn't work either:

```
http {
    [...]

    map $http_method $foo {
        POST on;
        default off;
    }

    server {
        [...]
        location /example {
            [...]

            proxy_cache_revalidate $foo;
        }
    }
}
```

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid value "$foo" in "proxy_cache_revalidate" directive, it must be "on" or "off" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:251
```

It seems like nginx really isn't built for this. I can't find much information on the internet either. Is there any workaround or more reasonable approach that I can use?